# Why should I avoid the ~> expression in 'Gemfile' file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm doing an online course about ruby on rails, and whenever they show us how to add a gem to the Gemfile before installation they said 'do not add the ~> or =< sign before the number version. but when I read the documentation of these gems they say to add it including this sign.

i.e. the bootstrap-sass gem

**1.** According to the documentation: gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 4.3.3'

**2.** According to the online course: gem 'bootstrap-sass', '4.3.3'

what's the meaning of this sign and why should I avoid using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those symbols are version specifiers according to [bundler's documentation](http://bundler.io/gemfile.html) :

> Most of the version specifiers, like >= 1.0, are self-explanatory. The specifier ~> has a special meaning, best shown by example. ~> 2.0.3 is identical to >= 2.0.3 and < 2.1. ~> 2.1 is identical to >= 2.1 and < 3.0. ~> 2.2.beta will match prerelease versions like 2.2.beta.12.

Comment: So you could say ~> is like a range between the actual version and the next release, or am I wrong? I tried to search for it in google but it won't recognize the symbol. So I guess they told us to not include this sign to avoid any unexpected behavior or something different from waht they show in the course's videos.

Comment: I can't speak for the course's intentions in instructing you to do that but it is a range between major releases(2.0-2.1) but still including minor releases(2.0.7).

Comment: yeah, I guess they do it to keep us in the side of caution by using just the specific version of the gem. thanks four your help!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's to specify the version number so that non-breaking updates can be performed according to http://semver.org . With a.b.c style version number, the number in a place represents major version. Changes to major versions can include non backward compatible changes. The number in b place is minor version number. Changes to minor versions can include improvements but no backward incompatible breaks(theorectically). The version number in c place represents patch version which is for bug fixes and patches. So in order to trust that the gem you isnt breaking if we bundle update, it's a good practice to use ~ for specifying gem versions. The actual rule is in the above answer so i wont repeat here. But keep in mind that it's not a hard rule. There might be gems that do not follow semver style strictly. Thus, some people trade the risk off with benefits of getting patch and improvement updates by specifying exact version number.

Comment: Yep, I guess it depends on evaluating the cost of the benefits: you can have the up-to-date gem but maybe it would break something. thanks for your explanation!